# why select() continuous return 0 sometimes

Tags: c, linux, select, tcp

I have a problem about select() in arm linux platform, the one side is arm linux as tcp client, the other side is pc as tcp server. The tcp client connected to server and receives data from server in fixed interval time ,like 5ms. The most of time, the select works fine, but sometimes happens strange things, that function select() continuous returns zero(timeout),after that select return normal, but size of read data is abnormal,like follows photo.

Is anybody knows that the reason ? thanks a lot.

[image]
[image]

```
    while(scan->is_child_thread_active)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
        w_time.tv_sec = 0; 
        w_time.tv_usec = (100*1000);//100ms
        if (scan->tcp_socket_fd > 0)
        {
            FD_SET(scan->tcp_socket_fd, &read_fd);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        mxfd = scan->tcp_socket_fd;
        if ((n_ready=select(mxfd + 1, &read_fd, (fd_set *) NULL, (fd_set *) NULL, &w_time)) < 0 )
        {
            print_err("select error: %s \n", strerror(errno));
            close(scan->tcp_socket_fd);
            scan->tcp_socket_fd = -1;
            continue;
        }
        if (0x00 == n_ready ) 
        {
            print_err("select timeout \n");
            continue;
        }
        scan->handleSocketRead(scan, read_fd, scan->tcp_socket_fd);
    }
```

coding of handle for reading as follows

```
if (sock_fd > 0 && FD_ISSET(sock_fd, &read_fd_set)) 
{
    if ((n_read = recv(sock_fd, scan->tcp_buffer_, TCP_BUF_SZ, 0))<=0) 
    {
        print_err("read tcp error,fd= %d:%s\n", sock_fd, strerror(errno));
        close(sock_fd);
        sock_fd = -1;
        return;
    }
    curr_data_time_ = get_ms_time_pf();
    RBT_MS_T delta_time = curr_data_time_ - last_data_time_;
    printf("rcv data len %d , delta time = %llu\n", n_read, delta_time);
    scan->writeBufferBack(scan->tcp_buffer_, n_read);
    while( scan->handleNextPacket() ) {}
    last_data_time_ = get_ms_time_pf();


}
```

By the way, the board under running in arm core freescale imx6q. And the longest frozen lasts more than 1 second in follows photo, and other log shows that the time sometimes lasts 5 seconds or even more longer.

**Is anything wrong configuration in linux ?**

Comment: Show your read code. There seem to be a lot of invalid assumptions here.

Comment: The given code is not the one that produced the output (timeout messages are clearly not the right ones). So please be consistent, if not there is no way to say something interesting if the symptoms are for a code that is not the one presented. Please also tell us why you said "read data is abnormal"? Through what you gave, we cannot say.

Comment: "*always return 0 sometimes*" hm, always or sometimes?

Comment: "*`scan->tcp_socket_fd > 0`*" 0 is a valid file descriptor.

Comment: codes has been already added in

Comment: The fact is that the pc tcp server sends data to client in fixed interval time as 5ms.

Comment: The fact is that the pc tcp server sends data to client in fixed interval time as 5ms. And what i said of that "abnormal" data means that the data from server likely  be blocked  in somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the POSIX `select()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, the `pselect()` and `select()` functions shall return the total number of bits set in the bit masks. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned, and errno shall be set to indicate the error.

Zero is a perfectly legitimate result, meaning there was no detected activity on the file descriptor(s).

Network traffic is not guaranteed to be delivered smoothly.  If that's a problem for your use, you need to address the network as there's no problem with the code.

Comment: the arm board is directly connected with pc computer by the ethernet cable.In theory, there is very very little problem of hardware or something else like router.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is not a Real Time OS. That means that while its multi-tasking is normally smooth, and every task runs as if it has a full system for itself, contentions can occur. In that case, some process can be frozen for a small period of time.

When I read your output, the longest frozen occurence only lasts 1231 ms, slightly more than one second. It is rather long for a computer, but can happen depending of other tasks, disk and network speed, temperature (not fully a joke here...) etc.

The second one lasts for 15 ms, which could be caused by a single slow IO operation.

If you do not use a RTOS, you should be prepared do things like that.

Comment: thanks your reply. I do a test that two pc computer do same testing, both of them  running ubuntu system.the result is ok, not happened like the upon things .